# Преобразование Map<List<Object>, List<Object>> в Map<Object, List<Object>>

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream

Есть часть кода; в ней я из ответа сервиса должен вытянуть Map следующего вида:

```
Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>> specialistsMap = specialistsResponse.getSpecialists().stream().collect(groupingBy(SpecialistInfo::getSpecializations));
```

Но по факту из этого стрима возвращается `Map<List<Specialization>, List<SpecialistInfo>>.`

Метод `getSpecialists()` возвращает `List<SpecialistInfo> specialists;`и каждый из объектов `SpecialistInfo` содержит список в себе. То есть метод `getSpecializations` тоже возвращает `List<Specialization> specializations`

Мне нужно сгруппировать эту мапу в мапу вида `Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>>`. 
Как я могу это сделать через stream API?

Comment: Так правильно. Оно и группирует по объекту листа. То есть у вас будут группы специалистов с одинаковыми списками(Однако помните, что именно одинаковыми наборами - сравнивает по индексам) специализаций. А вы чего хотите?

Comment: @Miron мне нужно сгруппировать, одна специальность - список специалистов, даже если какой-то специалист высветится возле другой специальности

Comment: То есть нужно слить все специальности спецов в один лист(без повторов), а потом к каждой специальности отнести список специалистов, имеющих эту специальность в своем листе.

Comment: Думаю, что идти через stream - извращение. Намного проще и понятней для читающих код реализовать без stream, imho

Answer (score 1):

Следует применить `Stream::flatMap` к стриму, полученному из списка специализаций и преобразовать его в поток неких пар `Pair<Specialization, SpecialistInfo>`, или же пар "ключ-значение" при помощи `Map.entry`.

Затем выполняется обычная группировка по ключу с использованием вложенного коллектора `Collectors.mapping`:

```java
List<SpecialistInfo> data = specialistsResponse.getSpecialists();

Map<Specialization, List<SpecialistInfo>> specialistsMap = data
    .stream()  // Stream<SpecialistInfo>
    .flatMap(info -> info.getSpecializations()
        .stream().map(spec -> Map.entry(spec, info)) 
    ) // Stream<Map.Entry<Specialization, SpecialistInfo>>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())
    ));
```